# Cloud9 Visual Studio Keymap

Tags: visual-studio, cloud9-ide, keymapping

Is there a keymap file for Cloud9 that makes the keybindings Visual-Studio-like?

(I know I can create it myself if I don't find one. Also, a Google search did not show any results.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no Visual Studio like key bindings in Cloud9 but you can use the key bindings editor from the preferences to customize the key bindings.